# why are the flags I submit with my script causing a "command not found" error

Tags: bash, flags

I'm very new to bash scripting, but I'm trying to write this script in an effort to learn bash / make my life easier. the title basically says everything, below is a snippet of the code in question.

this is how I call the script, along with the errors I get:

```
[root@vlab024200 ~]# ./vm_setup.sh "vlab024200" "5.0_SP1"
./vm_setup.sh: line 6: =vlab024200: command not found
./vm_setup.sh: line 9: =10.204.128.28: command not found
./vm_setup.sh: line 10: =AC_or_IDP: command not found
```

beyond the below snippet of vm_setup.sh, I have several log messages that call $vm in the log message. they omit the $vm variable and read things similar to "editing interface config file to take  as the host address."

being new to bash, I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to implement flags in a bash script. I've been reading up on how to perform input validation which I'll add, but I can't find anything on why my script isn't properly taking in the first two flags I give. I'd love some help with this script, but ultimately I want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script configures the hostname, hosts and interface cfg file.
# After the network is configured the VM is then registered installs
# wget, vim downloads NAM and restarts VM

# define values unique to this machine
$vm=$1
case $1 in
    vlab024200)
        $newIP="10.204.128.28"
        $role=AC_or_IDP
        ;;
    vlab024201)
        $newIP="10.204.128.29"
        $role=AC_or_IDP
        ;;
    vlab024202)
        $newIP="10.204.128.30"
        $role=AC_or_IDP
        ;;
    vlab024203)
        $newIP="10.204.128.31"
        $role=AG
        ;;
    vlab034305)
        $newIP="10.204.130.175"
        $role=AG
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: You don't put `$` at the beginning of a variable when you're assigning it. So `$vm=$1` should be `vm=$1`, and the same for all the other variable assignments.

Comment: If you had simply pasted your script into shellcheck.net it would have told you this.

Comment: never head of shellcheck.net - thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove those $ signs. You need to add dollar signs only when you are using those variables again in your code.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script configures the hostname, hosts and interface cfg file.
# After the network is configured the VM is then registered installs
# wget, vim downloads NAM and restarts VM

# define values unique to this machine
$vm=$1
case $1 in
  vlab024200)
    newIP="10.204.128.28"
    role=AC_or_IDP
    ;;
  vlab024201)
    newIP="10.204.128.29"
    role=AC_or_IDP
    ;;
vlab024202)
    newIP="10.204.128.30"
    role=AC_or_IDP
    ;;
vlab024203)
    newIP="10.204.128.31"
    role=AG
    ;;
vlab034305)
    newIP="10.204.130.175"
    role=AG
    ;;
esac
```